# Create lambda trigger each time my clients email receives a mail

Tags: python, aws-lambda, cloud, imap, pop3

I am creating a SaaS where each client creates an email for support. This way, each time someone from my client's organization needs support, he just sends an email to that direction and a ticket is generated automatically.

The old version periodically checks for new emails connected through IMAP. But I want a serverless approach using AWS Lambda.

Is there anyway I could **trigger** the function each time a mail is received instead of checking for unread mail every X time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use-case for [AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/?nc1=h_ls). You can register your domain and you mail addresses there and create inbound rules which can invoke a lambda on mail received.

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible.

There are two ways to send incoming email events to a Lambda function. The first method is to use a Lambda action in your receipt rule to send the event record directly to the function. The second method is to use an Amazon SNS action in your receipt rule to send the event records to Amazon SNS, and then add the Lambda function as a subscribing endpoint to the Amazon SNS topic.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-lambda-event.html